# Prolog making a list of terms in a function

Tags: prolog

For a school assignment we were supposed to 'remake' [unify_with_occurs_check/2](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=unify_with_occurs_check/2) without using any other built-in predicates directly related to the occurs-check or to sound unification, so that it works somewhat like this:

```
?- occurs(X, f(Y,g(X))). 
true.

?- occurs(X, f(Y,g(b))). 
false.
```

However, I've been trying this for hours, with no succes, and I can't find any hints to what built in predicates I should use for this.

So far I've come up with the following:

```
occurs(X, Func):-
dynamic F/Count,
functor(Func, F, Count),
findall(_, Func, Terms),
member(Term, Terms),
X == Term.
```

and

```
occurs(X, _(Terms)):-
TermList = [Terms],
member(Term, TermList),
X == Term.
```

But these require the variable 'Terms' to be bound to multiple terms at once (without being a list), thus resulting in an error.

So I need to make something that will make a list of all the variables within a (dynamic) function.

I have found [term_variables/2](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=term_variables/2) which does exactly what I want, however, my TA said I am also probably not allowed to use this :/

How could I begin to 'recreate' `term_variables/2`?

EDIT - SOLVED:

This is a working solution, thanks to Paulo Moura;

```
occurs(X, Func):-
\+ var(Func),
Func =.. [_ | Terms],
member(Term, Terms),
X == Term.

occurs(X, Func):-
\+ var(Func),
Func =.. [_ | Terms],
member(Term, Terms),
occurs(X, Term).
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define a `term_variables/2` predicate yourself by using the standard `=../2` to convert a term to a list and then recursively traversing the list while collecting the variables with the help of the `var/1` standard predicate.

Comment: Thanks! I totally forgot about =../2 this is exactly what I was searching for.